# How to apply css class to single items in ngFor

Tags: html, css, angular

I have two *ngFors in which the first one displays the text names of venues and uses (mouseenter) and (mouseleave) to call functions that change the color of pins on a map below the names. The second *ngFor is for displaying map pins for each venue. The maps pin color is controlled by the [iconUrl]="iconColor" in the ngfor.

The problem is that when I hover over the text of the venue name, every map pin changes color, instead of just the single pin that I want to change.

What would be the best way to go about this?

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div>
    <div align="center">
      <div *ngFor="let venue of mapVenues">
        <div class="venue-name" (mouseenter)="markerHovered()" (mouseleave)="markerNotHovered()">
          {{ venue }}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [zoom]="11" (mapready)="markerAnimation()">
      <agm-marker *ngFor='let show of usersShows'
      [latitude]="show.venue.lat"
      [longitude]="show.venue.lng"
      [animation]="animation"
      [iconUrl]="iconColor"
      ></agm-marker>
    </agm-map>
  </div>
</body>
```

Typescript:

```
  markerHovered() {
    this.hovered = true;
    this.iconColor = 'https://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter_withshadow&chld=%E2%80%A2|4286f4';
  }

  markerNotHovered() {
    this.hovered = false;
    this.iconColor = 'https://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter_withshadow&chld=%E2%80%A2|FF0000';
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `hovered` property to `usersShows` object, and then use condition to hovered object to apply url.

```
<agm-marker *ngFor='let show of usersShows'
  [latitude]="show.venue.lat"
  [longitude]="show.venue.lng"
  [animation]="animation"
  [iconUrl]="show.hovered ? iconColor : ''"
  ></agm-marker>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `[ngClass]`:

```
<div [ngClass]="hovered?'hovered-venue':'venue-name'" (mouseenter)="markerHovered()" (mouseleave)="markerNotHovered()">
          {{ venue }}
        </div>
```

And define your style for class `'hovered-venue'` as you like, ex:

```
.hovered-venue {
color: red;
}
```